# azure logic app HTTP bad request

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

i'm using HTTP post request in azure logic app to send data to Api.In my case im getting values from SQL stored procedure and put in to HTTP post request body.but when i request it's show as bad request.

required format :

{"UserName":"test","Code":102},{"UserName2":"test2","Code2":103}

Error format :

```
   { "UserName\": \"test\" , \"Code\": \"1000001013\"},{ \"UserName2\": \"test2\" , \"Code2\": \"1000001013\"}
```

anyone can help to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Please share what you are trying to do, e.g. a screenshot of your workflow and the JSON code behind so people can better understand the issue.